# Programmatically pressing a imageButton doesn't execute immediately

Tags: android

`playTune` is called whenever a user selects a button. The problem is the line `myButton.setPressed(true);` is only called after the tune is played. This defies logic, so I'm wondering whether Android lines up events in an queue? I would like the line `myButton.setPressed(true);` to be called as it appears in the code. i.e. before a note is played.

```
private void playTune() {

  isTunePlaying = true;

  //Get no of notes user selected
  String selectedValue = noteCountValues[noteCountIdx];
  Log.v(LOG_TAG, "selectedValue:"+selectedValue+" noteCountIdx:"+noteCountIdx);
  int noOfNotes;
  if ("ALL".equals(selectedValue)){
   noOfNotes = 50;
  }
  else{
   noOfNotes = Integer.parseInt(selectedValue);
  }

  TuneManager tuneManager = TuneManager.getInstance(this);
  Log.v(LOG_TAG, "tuneNamesIdx:"+tuneNamesIdx);   
  Tune tune = tuneManager.getTune(tuneNamesIdx+1);

  Log.v(LOG_TAG, " tuneTitle:"+tune.getTitle()+" tuneNoOfNotes:"+tune.getNotes().size());

  //Initialise expectedNotes
  expectedNotes = new StringBuffer();

  //Get notes and play
  List<Note> notes = tune.getNotes();  
  //for (Note note:tune.getNotes()){
  for (int i=1; i<=notes.size() && i<=noOfNotes; i++){

   Log.v(LOG_TAG, "i:"+i+" notesSize:"+notes.size()+" noOfNotes:"+noOfNotes);   

   //Highlight note
   if (isHighlightNotesOn){    
    final View myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.middle_c);    
    myButton.setPressed(true);       
   }    

   Note note = notes.get(i-1);
   int notePos = soundManager.getNotePosition(note);
   Log.v(LOG_TAG, "current note:"+note.getName()+" playing notePos:"+notePos+" setting duration:"+note.getDurationMS());   
   soundManager.playSound(notePos);

   //Add to expectedNotes
   expectedNotes.append(" "+note.getName()+",");   

   //Sleep for the duration
   try{
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(note.getDurationMS());//sleep for 1000 ms
   }
   catch(InterruptedException ie){

   }
  }

  isTunePlaying = false;  

  //Initialise actualNotesPlayed i.e. start from after the tine has finished
  actualNotesPlayed = new StringBuffer();     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are running into, but if you cause an event from something event driven (happening on the UI thread) it of course cannot be processed on the UI thread until after your current event handler returns.

Comment: Yes. That makes some sense. I probably didnt give you much to go on to come up with a solution. The user presses a 'Play Tune' button. This us handled by a call to the above playTune method, where it runs through a list of notes, sounding them each one in turn. I assume from your answer that the call to setPressed happens on the UI thread which has to wait until the playTune button has finished its processing. However, I put the playTune button in its own handler but I still get the problem

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
  
  Log.v(LOG_TAG, "View id is:"+v.getId());   
  
  if (v.getId() == R.id.play_tune_button) {
   Handler myHandler = new Handler();
   myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
       public void run()
       {
     Log.v(LOG_TAG, "In handler new Thread"); 
           playTune();
       }
   });
   Log.v(LOG_TAG, "OTHER THREAD");      
  }                                                                  Any ideas?

Comment: Solved it! When listening to onClick button for screen event, execute in nonUIThread:  else if (v.getId() == R.id.play_tune_button) {

   // Fire off a thread to do some work that we shouldn't do directly in the UI thread
         Thread t = new Thread() {
             public void run() {
                 playTune();
             }
         };
         t.start();   
  }                                                                      But when highlighting a note, get handle to the UIThread, using  runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){ ...etc. I'm gonna down pub to get smashed WOo Hoo!